# Reloading tab activity onResume but don't want to reload on tab switch

Tags: android

I'm not sure if my title is clear so let me explain.

Tab A - contains a listview populated from a database
Tab B - search form

I need to update the contents of tab A after coming back from a search results screen. Using onResume() works great but this also reloads the Tab whenever I click back and forth through between tabs. Is there another method I could use here?

EDIT: I guess it's a bit more complex than this. The search form loads a new intent that displays the results in a listview. An item can be select which then loads a item info screen. From here the user can select from a few option, one being Add. This is the action that needs to reload the original listview in Tab A.

Answer (score 1):

In tab A trigger the search activity with `startIntentForResult()` and then in `onActivityResult()` get your Adapter of the `ListView` and set the new data of the ListView.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think it's a bit more complex than I first let on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onWindowFocusChanged method  if you need to  add some more process when getting the focus for a particular tab..

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //You can add your own method to refresh data within the tab                 //(Ex:  refreshData())

super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
```

}